# run streamline.js gives error "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

I ran `npm install streamline -g` as it specifies in the [github doc](https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs#installation)

However, when I ran `_node` on windows command line....I got:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

I checked my `AppData\Roaming\npm` (where node modules are installed, and I verified that this path is indeed in my environment variables), I can see that **_node.cmd** just lies there along with **bower**, but I have no problem invoking bower from windows command line

I think windows knows that I have "_node.cmd", since before the installation, the error message I am getting is:

> '_node' is not recognized as an internal or external command

So I suspect that the **underscore** somehow broke windows command line, anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?  I am having the same problem, and it appears that the _node scripts are bash scripts, but I am trying to run them from the windows command line (e.g. not the Windows Subsystem for Linux) as I need the Windows version of node, not the WSL version.

Comment: @Michael I end up using `npm run-script build` + `"scripts": {"build": "_node -c ConfusedDev.code" }` in "package.json" as a workaround